# Very strange SQL Select error when selecting data from Views

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I'm working with Greenplum in pgAdmin, and I have a view called MyView. When I select from the view like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE State = 'NY' OR State = 'CA';
```

it works fine.

However, when I remove the OR condition:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE State = 'NY';
```

I get the error: "**Can't serialize transient record types, SQL state XX000**".

This is very strange, and I couldn't find much information about this error. I have tried creating the view again with a different input table, same error. Then I tried to create it as a table instead of a view, and that works as expected, so this only occurs with views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the view definition and the structure of the table(s) the view is based on?

Comment: The view is a union of several select queries. The actual definition is quite complicated. I'm not sure what you mean by "structure" of the underlying table, but it is a fairly standard table with many columns, both character and numeric.

Comment: You need to simplify your table definition and your view to the point that a) it still produces the error, and b) we can paste it into our own versions of PostgreSQL *and get the same error*. Paste that simplified table definition and view definition into your question.

Comment: What exact version of PostgreSQL are you using? Execute: `SELECT version()` and paste the result here, please.

Comment: I'm using this for a Greenplum database, if that makes any difference:

"PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.2.7.2 build 1) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on Feb 25 2014 18:05:04"

Comment: @AdmiralWen It makes a big difference... Greenplum is a different DBMS, with different behaviour (and different bugs).

Comment: @AdmiralWen If you're using Greenplum, you need to say so up front. It's based on PostgreSQL, but it's a fork of a very old version. It's like going to the `[mysql]` tag and asking questions about Drizzle as if it was MySQL without mentioning what you were really using.

Comment: BTW, the message `Can't serialize transient record types` does not appear in the PostgreSQL source code, at least in 9.4. I'd say it's related to Greenplum's distributed query architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. The datasets used and the view definition are very complicated, and I'm not sure if I have the authority to post them here. I can try to replicate a simpler version though.

For now, I've realized that if I use `IF State LIKE NY` rather than `= NY`, it somehow works.

Comment: Does the view contain data type conversion (or, should it contain explicit data conversion)? I have struck this error message once before where it was solved by casting strings to timestamps (it was an implicit conversion, and needed to be explicit). Given that the view is a union it could be something like this.